# Make solr consume queries from AMQ (rabbitMQ or ActiveMQ)

Tags: solr, amqp

I would like to make my application to interact with an Apache Solr sever using an AMQ queue (RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ). Therefore I would like to ask if there is any implementation of this kind, if not, where can I find information how to implement such a connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration case is one that might be suited to using Apache Camel. Camel allows you to create routes that link different systems together - in this case Solr (or even Lucene directly) and an AMQP broker.

For example, you may want to gain some additional efficiencies by hitting Lucene directly and leverage Camel's Lucene component (see http://camel.apache.org/lucene.html ) and create a route such as:

```
from: amqp:exchange:queue:routingKey
to: lucene:searcherName:query
```

In just those two lines a message would be retrieved from an AMQP queue, processed by Lucene and then replied back to. You could also continue using Solr's REST API by leveraging Camel's HTTP component, such as:

```
from: amqp:exchange:queue:routingKey
to: jaxb:marshal
to: http://solr.server/api/uri
to: jaxb:marshal
```

In that route you would fetch a message from an AMQP queue, marshal it as JSON or XML, send it to a Solr URI and then unmarshall the response back into an object.

There's nothing pre-cooked that will give you this functionality out of the box, but you can leverage several integration frameworks to help you wire the systems together.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a 'proxy' application that does the following:

1. Get a message from the queue
2. Send the corresponding query to Solr via HTTP (which is its standard interface)
3. Put a message in the queue with the query results.

Should be quite simple...

Comment: Thx. So far for me, it also seems to be the only option.

Comment: @Skarab : you could also embed this in Solr, but I'd keep things separate.

Comment: This is the way that the Mongrel2 web server works. It sends messages to workers who collect parts of the result page, and each worker does one job, like a SOLR search, and sends back a message with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I created a data source to enable a data import handler to build documents from extracted JSON messages. It is called AMQPDataSource, however it currently only works with RabbitMQ and only with JSON formatted messages. But, I desire for it to work with other brokers hence the use of AMQP in the name.

Using it is similar to using the JDBC data source in a data import config.

The AMQP data source takes several parameters which are passed to it via the data import config. They are:

1. AMQPHost -> the server of the AMQP host
2. exchangeName -> the name of the AMQP exchange. If it doesn't exist,
   it will be created.
3. queueName -> the name of the AMQP queue. If it
   doesn't exist, it will be created.
4. nextDeliveryTimeoutMS -> max amount of time to wait for a message to be delivered.

When you run dataimport using this data source, dataimport will pull messages continually until the nextDeliveryTimeoutMS is exceeded.

I have created a JIRA issue for it and uploaded a patch. 
The JIRA issue is SOLR-3588.

Please feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just put a solr plugin that reads from a AMQP queue onto github.
https://github.com/ranoble/SolrMQ

It basically acts as a consumer and uses a existing update plugin to import and parse the update.

Probably not 100% production ready but I through 100000 separate updates at it and it handled them all without issue. Hoping to get some feedback on it.